# Read odd lines of a file text an add to a array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a text file with with the following lines of text:

```
https://i.imgur.com/9iLSS35.png
Delete page: https://imgur.com/delete/SbmZQDht9Xk2NbW
https://i.imgur.com/9iLSS336.png
Delete page: https://imgur.com/delete/SbmZQDht9Xk2NbW
https://i.imgur.com/9iLSS37.png
Delete page: https://imgur.com/delete/SbmZQDht9Xk2NbW
```

I need to read the odd lines and add to a array in bash. I have tried the following code but it generates a variable and not an array as I need.

`A=$(sed -n 1~2p ./upimagen.txt)`

How can I read the odd lines of the text file and add each line to an array and then access separately?

The result would be:

```
${A[0]}
https://i.imgur.com/9iLSS35.png
${A[1]}
https://i.imgur.com/9iLSS336.png
...
```

Comment: Do you really want the odd numbered lines, or do you want the lines that match `^https`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slight variation on John's answer using `awk`. Using either `readarray` or the synonymous `mapfile` reading from a *process substitution* is probably your best bet, e.g.

```
 readarray -t A < <(awk 'FNR % 2 {print $1}' ./upimagen.txt)
```

While there is nothing wrong with the direct initialization using command substitution, e.g. `A=( $(...) )`, if your files are large, or if you only need part of the range of lines, or say you have a custom function you want to run on every X number of elements read, `mapfile/readarray` offers a wide set of features over straight command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Array assignment requires an outer set of parentheses.

```
A=($(sed -n 1~2p ./upimagen.txt))
```

This will split on all whitespace, though, not just newlines. It will also expand any globs that use `*` or `?`. It's better to use `readarray` plus [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to ensure that each line is preserved as is:

```
readarray -t A < <(sed -n 1~2p ./upimagen.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` :

```
readarray -t A < <(awk 'NR%2' ./upimagen.txt)
```